# C# Expression Tree not accepting True

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have the following Expression in which I need to add always true condition

```
string tenantId = "";

Expression<Func<MongoIdentityUser, bool>> baseFilter = t => t.IsActive == true && t.IsApproved == true;

var constExpression = Expression.Constant(tenantId);
var paramExpression = baseFilter.Parameters[0]; //using the base filter paramater t=>
var callExp = Expression.PropertyOrField(paramExpression, "TenantId");
var ifParamIsNull = Expression.Equal(paramExpression, Expression.Constant(true));
var ifParamIsNotNull = Expression.Equal(callExp, constExpression);

var AndExp = Expression.AndAlso(baseFilter.Body, string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tenantId) ? ifParamIsNull : ifParamIsNotNull);

var result =  Expression.Lambda<Func<MongoIdentityUser, bool>>(AndExp, paramExpression);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**when I run the code I received the following error**
[image]

Following is the exception message

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: The binary
> operator Equal is not defined for the types
> 'LMS.Entities.DomainModels.Identity.MongoIdentityUser' and
> 'System.Boolean'.

**While I need the following output**

```
t => t.IsActive == true && t.IsApproved == true && true
```

If I change from true to null in the below expression code works fine

```
 var ifParamIsNull = Expression.Equal(paramExpression, Expression.Constant(null));
```

Comment: In the first block, `ifParamIsNull` is assigned the expression `t == true`. Since `t` is a `MongoIdentityUser`, that obviously won't work. In the latter one, it's assigned to the expression `t == null`, which is valid and looks like what the variable name suggests. It looks like you fixed it. What's your question?

Comment: @madreflection actually I need the t=>true in the output. I am trying to create the following expression tree t => t.IsActive == true && t.IsApproved == true && true

Comment: There's a big difference between `t == true` and `true`. The expression `Expression.Equal(paramExpression, Expression.Constant(true))` is comparing `t` with `true`. Can you explain *why* you need such an odd expression in the first place? This feels like an XY problem.

Comment: `&& true` is a logical identity, so it doesn't affect the condition at all. You don't need it.

Comment: you are right. I was using the wrong way. Just resolve the issue by modifying the logic.